# Why does libc++ call_once uses a shared mutex for all calls?

Tags: c++, multithreading, libc++, std-call-once

I'm reading the [source code](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/905e93244187a88614fc866b6089ecc3f7b16105/libcxx/src/mutex.cpp#L207) of `call_once` in libc++, and curious about the usage of a shared mutex. Here's the implementation inside `mutex.cpp`. Doesn't this mean `call_once(f1)` and `call_once(f2)` compete for the same mutex even if they are different functions. Thanks.

```cpp
#ifndef _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_THREADS
_LIBCPP_SAFE_STATIC static __libcpp_mutex_t mut = _LIBCPP_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
_LIBCPP_SAFE_STATIC static __libcpp_condvar_t cv = _LIBCPP_CONDVAR_INITIALIZER;
#endif

void __call_once(volatile once_flag::_State_type& flag, void* arg,
                 void (*func)(void*)) {
  __libcpp_mutex_lock(&mut);
  ...
}
```

I'm hoping someone one can clarify if this is intended, and if so what's the reason behind.

Comment: Perhaps it uses some kind of global state, and needs to protect that from execution by multiple threads?

Comment: How do you propose to implement `call_once` with a mutex per call? You don't know how many calls there are. The library receives a call to `call_once`, what should it do?

Comment: @n.m. each `std::once_flag` could have it's own mutex

Answer (score 1):

It does use a single mutex for all calls to `std::call_once` but it's only locked for as long as it takes to set or check the once flag. Unless you have hundreds of calls to `std::call_once` I can't see this having a significant performance impact.

It was probably implemented this way for both simplicity and the performance of the usual case of only having a small number of uses of `call_once`. It'd me much more complex (or even impossible) to implement a separate mutex for each flag.